# Jenkins Global Email Notification Setting

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins configuration with ~100 jobs. Whenever any of those jobs fails I want an email notification to be sent to a particular email address. How can I do this without adding a post-build action for every individual job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something like **Configuration Slicing Plugin** https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin. It enables global configuration different aspects

Comment: How do I apply this configuration for all jobs at all? Looks like the plugin supports folders, so the workaround would be to add all folders. But I'm looking for something like `*` wildcard